# How to get the name and maximum values of points for each year? (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

This is my code so far It's in T-SQL.

I'm stuck at adding the **driver_name** column. What kind of aggregation am I supposed use?

```sql
SELECT MAX(race_points) max_points, year, driver_name
FROM 

    (SELECT

        CONCAT(forename,' ',surname) AS driver_name,
        year,
        (CONVERT(FLOAT,points)) AS race_points     
     
    FROM 
            results AS r

            INNER JOIN constructors AS c
            ON r.constructorId = c.constructorId

            INNER JOIN drivers AS d
            ON r.driverId = d.driverId

            INNER JOIN races AS rc
            ON r.raceId = rc.raceId) AS sub
GROUP BY year;
```

This is how **sub** looks like

| driver_name | year | race_points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2010 | 2 |
| a | 2011 | 3 |
| b | 2011 | 4 |
| b | 2012 | 3 |
| c | 2012 | 4 |

I'm trying to make it look lie this

| driver_name | year | max_points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2010 | 2 |
| b | 2011 | 4 |
| c | 2012 | 4 |

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `row_number()` you can give your rows numbers according on how you partition the numbers. If you sort that accordingly you can select row number 1  from every group.

```
WITH cte as
(
   SELECT
     CONCAT(forename,' ',surname) AS driver_name,
     year,
     (CONVERT(FLOAT,points)) AS race_points,
     row_number() over (partition by year order by (CONVERT(FLOAT,points)) desc) as rn     
   FROM 
     results AS r    
     INNER JOIN constructors AS c ON r.constructorId = c.constructorId
     INNER JOIN drivers AS d ON r.driverId = d.driverId
     INNER JOIN races AS rc ON r.raceId = rc.raceId
)
SELECT * FROM cte 
WHERE rn = 1
```